# output in different windows

Tags: matlab, output

Can I show 3-4 outputs(graphical output, Same images) in different windows using matlab.some thing like the following fig.

for more clarification-
example-

```
for i=1:10 
vid = videoinput('winvideo', 2);
set(vid,'FramesPerTrigger',2);
start(vid);
imageData=getdata(vid,1);
I=rgb2gray(imageData);
figure,imshow(I);
end
```

In this case 10 frames will be shown in 10 different figure. Which I do not want to do. I want to show all the frames in same window, even if the frame changes every time.
[image]

I am not talking about figure or subfigure. And the output can be changed every time in the same window.

Regards,

Comment: What do you mean by "output"? Graphical output or command-style output?

Comment: graphical output. Same images

Comment: Not sure you can achieve that without referring to figures (figures are windows). One way is to create a figure that fits your entire screen, and have 4 panels in it.

Comment: Yeah I know, figures are window, but every time the output is changed it is displayed in a new figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call an already created figure using the simple code `figure(h)`. With this, no new figure window is created.

```
h = figure; %create figure
...
figure(h); %call the figure h and draw in it.
```

Using your code

```
h = figure;

for i=1:10   
  vid = videoinput('winvideo', 2);  
  set(vid,'FramesPerTrigger',2);  
  start(vid);  
  imageData=getdata(vid,1);  
  I=rgb2gray(imageData);  

  figure(h);

  imshow(I);  
end
```

Comment: hi, what if I want to make multiple windows as I asked in the original fig??

Comment: Hi- you can declare several of them like `h1 = figure; h2 = figure; ...; figure(h1) ...`. You can also set the figure's position using [this matlab link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/positioning-figures.html)

Comment: hi I have a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503494/output-positins-of-matlab-figures you might help me out

Answer (score 1):

The closest one can (probably) come to creating a simple rectangular box with an image and no title or menu bars is something like the following:

```
imagesc(randn(50)) % <-- display the image

axis off, set(gca,'Position',[0 0 1 1]), set(gcf,'menubar','none')
```

As far as I could unearth it is not possible to get rid of the title bar, see for instance [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/316968).

**edit**

Regarding your specific example, you can try `imagesc` or `image`, something like this:

```
hgcf1=figure;
imagesc(randn(50)); hgca1=gca; axis off, set(hgca1,'Position',[0 0 1 1])
set(hgcf1,'units','normalized','Position',[0.1 0.6 0.4 0.3],'menubar','none')

while 1
    pause(0.5)
    imagesc(randn(50)); 
end
```

If you want to use imshow:

```
hgcf1=figure;
imshow(randn(50));  hgca1=gca; 
set(hgca1,'Position',[0 0 1 1])
set(hgcf1,'units','normalized','menubar','none')
axis tight off
while 1
    pause(0.5)
    imshow(randn(50)); 
    hgca1=gca;
    set(hgca1,'Position',[0 0 1 1])
    axis tight
end
```