# Output positions of Matlab figures

Tags: matlab, output, figure

I want to show my graphical output of a Matlab program in a different pre-fixed window. So, that whenever I run the program, the output should be inside this figure. I followed a [tutorial on the Matlab website](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/positioning-figures.html) and the created the figure as follows:

[image: Created figure]

Until here everything is fine.

Now, when I what to show some output inside this figure with `figure(1)`, `Imshow(A)`, the figure size and position is automatically changed, which I do not want. I get something like this:

[image: Unwanted result]

Now my question is: How do I show the outputs in the pre-calculated position and size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try displaying your images with `'InitialMagnification'` set to `'fit'`:

```
>> figure(1); imshow( A, 'InitialMagnification', 'fit' );
```

If this does not work, you might try set `'Position'` of figure after showing the image.
Alternatively, you might want to consider using `imagesc` with `axis image` to display the images.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

(  0. all of the figures are already created, but without the images loaded)

1. Save the position before loading the images, eg. like: PosFig1=get(,'Position')...
2. Load the images etc.
3. Set the figures to there old poistions, like: set((,'Position',PosFig1)

Of course, you could put the positions into some kind of structure, to make the code to look nicer and more flexibel and so on :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I already did get position and set position, that is why they are in a fixed position.